# connect to existing database in laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have just started using Laravel 4 and have been reading "code bright". I am attempting to migrate one of my applications to the Laravel framework. I have seen how to create a new database using the schema builder and migrations, but I already have a database with a few tables and hundreds of rows. how would I use models in Laravel 4 to query this database? I have already added the connection in the config.

Answer (score 1):

You would have to create models for each table.  If the table name is plural, it would be best to use it's singular name as the class name for the model.

For cases where that doesn't work (where the name may not be plural or ends in something like 'ies' that may confuse Laravel), just set the property `protected $table = 'tablename';` to coincide with the table you wish to create a model for.

After that, follow the documention on Eloquent for setting up any relationships you may need to make.

It may be possible, and probably a good idea, to make migrations for each of the tables, though that may be quite time consuming.  You'd have to make each migration file as well as fill out the migrations table Laravel uses by hand.